# React - help needed to make the filter working

Tags: reactjs, filter

I would need help with the filter not working. Basically, I have two sets of data (these are arrays of objects). One called companies.json and another one called items.json.

The id is unique in the **companies.json** [{**"id": 2**,..."},{...}].

We can retrieve this value in the **items.json** [{"_id": 1,**"companyId": 2**, "name":"aaa"},{"_id": 2,"companyId": 6, "name":"aaa"}, {"_id": 3,**"companyId": 2**, "name":"aaa"},...].

So, I fetched the data and can isolate them. From there, I wanted to do a filter that must display only the list of items that belong to the "companyId": 19962 but for some reason this does not work and I get the full list of items...

Any help would be much appreciated. Here is my code. I added some comments for convenience.

```
const MyList = () => {
  // Store the name of the company typed in the input
  const [companyInput, setCompanyInput] = useState('');

  // Store the list of companies from the file companies.json
  const [companiesList, setCompaniesList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/data/companies.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then ((response)=>setCompaniesList(response))
  }, []);

  // console.log(companiesList);

  // Store the id of the company
  const [companyId, setCompanyId] = useState('');

  // Allows to update the state and store the name of the company typed into companyInput
  const handleCompanyInput = (ev) => {
    setCompanyInput(ev.target.value);
  }

  // Allows to compare the name of the company stored in companyInput and compare this value with the list of companies stored into companiesList.
  // If there is a match, then return the id of the company.
  const HandleIdCompany = () => {
    const companyObj = companiesList.find((item) => item.name.toLowerCase() == companyInput.toLowerCase());
    setCompanyId(companyObj.id)
  };

  // If companyId is found, then display the list of products
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/data/items.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((response) => setItems(response))
  }, []);

  console.log(`items ===> ${JSON.stringify(items)}`); // [{},{}]
  console.log(`companyId ===> ${JSON.stringify(companyId)}`); // 13334

  // Use the filter
  const [filterItems, setFilterItems] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilterItems(items);
  }, [items]);

  console.log(`filterItems ===> ${JSON.stringify(filterItems)}`); // [{},{}]

  const filteredUsers = items.filter(item => item.id = companyId);

  return (
    <div>
      <DivCntr>
        <label>Enter Company Name</label>
        <input placeholder='Type a company' id='coinput' type='text' onChange={handleCompanyInput} />
        <button onClick={HandleIdCompany}>Get the id for this specific company</button>
        <button >Get the list of items for this specific company</button>
      </DivCntr>
      <div>
        <p>{companyInput}</p>
        <p>{companyId}</p>

        <ul>
          {filteredUsers.map(item => (
            <li key={item._id}>{item.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Typo?  Your callback to `items.filter()` is *assigning*, not *comparing*.  Use `item.id === companyId` instead.  (Also, shouldn't it be `item.companyId === companyId`?)

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot David!  item.companyId === companyId is working. I get the list I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
// import items from '../data/items.json';
// import companies from '../data/companies.json';
import styled from "styled-components";

const MyList = () => {
  // Store the name of the company typed in the input
  const [companyInput, setCompanyInput] = useState('');

  // Store the list of companies from the file companies.json
  const [companiesList, setCompaniesList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/data/companies.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((response) => setCompaniesList(response))
  }, []);

  // console.log(companiesList);

  // Store the id of the company
  const [companyId, setCompanyId] = useState('');

  // Allows to update the state and store the name of the company typed into companyInput
  const handleCompanyInput = (ev) => {
    setCompanyInput(ev.target.value);
  }

  // Allows to compare the name of the company stored in companyInput and compare this value with the list of companies stored into companiesList.
  // If there is a match, then return the id of the company.
  const HandleIdCompany = () => {
    const companyObj = companiesList.find((item) => item.name.toLowerCase() == companyInput.toLowerCase());
    setCompanyId(companyObj.id)
  };

  // If companyId is found, then display the list of products
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/data/items.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((response) => setItems(response))
  }, []);

  console.log(`items ===> ${JSON.stringify(items)}`); // [{},{}]
  console.log(`companyId ===> ${JSON.stringify(companyId)}`); // 13334

  // Use the filter
  const [filterItems, setFilterItems] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setFilterItems(items);
  }, [items]);

  console.log(`filterItems ===> ${JSON.stringify(filterItems)}`); // [{},{}]

  const filteredUsers = items.filter(item => **item.companyId === companyId**);

  return (
    <div>
      <DivCntr>
        <label>Enter Company Name</label>
        <input placeholder='Type a company' id='coinput' type='text' onChange={handleCompanyInput} />
        <button onClick={HandleIdCompany}>Get the id for this specific company</button>
        <button >Get the list of items for this specific company</button>
      </DivCntr>
      <div>
        <p>{companyInput}</p>
        <p>{companyId}</p>

        <ul>
          {filteredUsers.map(item => (
            <div key={item._id}>
              <li>Name: {item.name}</li>
              <li>Price: {item.price}</li>
            </div>
          ))}
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).